# Table of content in PDF exported from Word links back to Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, table-of-contents

I have created a table of content in a document file and its working fine in Word but not when I'm saving it as PDF file. When I click on the links in the table of content in the PDF viewer, it is trying to open the docx file.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you clarify further what you mean by "not working in PDF"? What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you could upload your Word document somewhere and the resulting PDF that would be helpful. Very hard to troubleshoot otherwise.

Comment: The problem is, that the links contain full URLs instead of just an anchor. I don't know yet how to solve it though. A similar problem is described here: https://superuser.com/q/736517/176568