# MS Office Table of figures Change link base

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, links, table-of-contents

I got a document for updating in my work. In this document we have 'Table of Figures' at the beginning of document which provides link to all figures in document.

It works correctly when I check here in PC after the operation Update Table->Update Entire Table.

But these links are not working when document is opened in another machine. When I checked links are formed relative to destination of document in my PC.
For eg when the place mouse pointer near a link it shows `file///C:\Users\Administrator\....\document.doc`

There are a lot of figures so I just dont want to delete current one and create a new one, by spending large time. I dont need any link to outside of document. I am referencing only figures inside the document. So my question is Is there any easy way to change the link base from external to inside the file permanently.

Comment: I could narrow down the problem to figure captions in text frames. If the figure caption is a plain paragraph, the links are correct.

Comment: The problem also affects PDF documents created from the Word documents, if they are created with the "Export to PDF" feature.